# How to hide the z-indexed div if we click out side the div which is placed in user control in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

I am having a div in usercontrol and i am showing the div as i have given z-index and showing as a menu item and now if i click out side the z-indexed div then the z-indexed div must close .

Answer (score 0):

You would need to handle the click event of a parent html container, or possibly even the body itself.

For illustration something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").click(function(){
   // Check if a menu is displayed, if so hide it
   });
});
```

Your menu would also need some mechanism to indicate that it was currently open and a reference back to  close it.

Alternatively you could declare a global function that would close any open menu's on the click event.